# Can't access method from model

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following model:

```
import { EventConsumerModel } from './EventConsumerModel';

export class EventLogModel {

  private id: number;
  private event_type: string;
  private occurred_on: string;
  private producedDomain: string;
  private eventConsumers: EventConsumerModel[];

  constructor(values: Object = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, values);
  }

  public getEventConsumers(): EventConsumerModel[] {
    return this.eventConsumers;
  }
}
```

and

```
export class EventConsumerModel {

  private status: string;

  constructor(values: Object = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, values);
  }

  public getStatus(): string {
    return this.status;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to access the `getStatus()` method from inside of `EventConsumerModel`. Unfortunaly, this isn't working.

If I do something like:

```
for (let ec of this.events[0].getEventConsumers()) {
  console.log(ec.getStatus());
}
```

where `this.events` is of type `EventLogModel[]`; I get an error saying `ec.getStatus is not a function`.

My service for populating `this.events` looks like this:

```
public getEvents(batchId: string): Observable<EventLogModel[]> {
    return this.http.get(EVENTS_URL + batchId + EVENTS_ENDPOINT)
      .map((res: Response) => {
        const events = res.json().eventList;
        return events.map((e) => new EventLogModel(e));
      })
      .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
}
```

and a typical JSON response looks like this:

```
  "batchId": "2c9180855f359542015f35aa2d460d74",
  "status": "REJECTED",
  "createdTime": "2017-10-19T17:24:26Z",
  "eventList": [
    {
      "unique_id": 200168014,
      "id": "12091792-9020-4311-8bad-44fa8b69d218",
      "event_type": "com.adp.pi.eventmachine.PayFileProcessingCompleted",
      "partition_key": "2c9180855f359542015f35aa2d460d74",
      "occurred_on": "2017-10-19T17:24:26",
      "trace_id": "-8551048985939099152",
      "event_version": "1",
      "producedDomain": "PAY_FILE_STATUS",
      "eventConsumers": [
        {
          "status": "COMPLETED",
          "listener": "com.clientmanagement.hr.presentation.event.PayFileProcessingCompletedEventHandler",
          "consumedOn": "2017-10-19T17:24:27",
          "consumedDomain": "POLICY"
        }
      ],
      "consumedOn": "2017-10-19T17:24:27"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I'd ultimately like to be able to use the `getStatus()` function in HTML with binding.

**Edit:** It looks like it's never creating an `EventConsumerModel`. I put a `console.log()` in the constructor for that model and nothing came up. Might have to do with how I'm mapping objects in my service; but I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `Object.assign(this, values);` inside the constructor, it maps the input to the member variables, but isn't creating any instances for you. Therefore the `eventConsumers` member is just an array of objects and not an array of instances of `EventConsumerModel`.

So you have to set the member variable of `eventConsumers` explicitly:

```
interface EventLogResponse {
  id?: number, 
  event_type?: string, 
  occured_on?: string, 
  producedDomain?: string,
  eventConsumers?: Object[]
}

export class EventLogModel {

  private id: number;
  private event_type: string;
  private occurred_on: string;
  private producedDomain: string;
  private eventConsumers: EventConsumerModel[];

  constructor({ 
    eventConsumers,
    ...obj
  }: EventLogResponse = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, obj);
    this.eventConsumers = eventConsumers.map(ec => new EventConsumerModel(ev));
  }

  public getEventConsumers(): EventConsumerModel[] {
    return this.eventConsumers;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do I need that interface?

Comment: It's not important to have it, just for knowing the response type. You could omit it

Comment: How would you write it without the interface? You can't just change `EventLogResponse = {}` to `Object = {}`.

Comment: Replace it with `any` for example

Comment: Last question: Is it better practice to move the Interface into it's own file? or put it at the top of the class.

Comment: Depends on your preference, if you think it's tied to the model then leave it in the same file otherwise move it into its own. You could even make 1 file for multiple interfaces or models. Totally up to you